# Open java (android) project created in mac on Windows

Tags: java, android, windows, macos

So, I need to open an eclipse project in my computer. The project was build on a mac and my computer runs windows. Its seems like there is some code missing and when I try to run the app on my avd, I get “Unfortunately,  has stopped.”

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: does it tell you anything about WHY it has stopped? some more specifics about the error message would be helpful

Comment: no,it is the "normal" error when an aplicattion stops. "Unfortunately, SimpleRssReader has stopped".

Answer (score 0):

Android (Java) code has nothing to do with Windows or Mac machines - I'm guessing either your JDK versions are different between the two, or (more likely) you have a different version of the Android SDK.  Therefore, you have different versions of the AVD, so your app doesn't nicely transfer.  I would suggest running in debug mode and showing us the stack trace, so we can give more helpful information.